# How to add TextWatcher on Editext which is created at Runtime (programmatically)?

Tags: android

I want to use TextWatcher on EditText which is created at Runtime programmatically. But it is not working with EditText created at Runtime.

I used Model class for UI elements to be add at Runtime. And a Controller class having arraylist to store objects of Model class, my code is below,

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    EditText editText_A;
    RelativeLayout layout_root;
    Controller aController;
    int counter = 1;
    int id = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // inflate UI
        layout_root = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_root);
        editText_A = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_A);

        // controller object
        aController = (Controller) getApplication();

        // set last UI element into list
        aController.get_ui_list().add(new UI_Model(editText_A.getId()));

        // dynamic button
        Button add = new Button(this);
        Button remove = new Button(this);

        // set id/Text
        add.setId(id);
        remove.setId(++id);
        add.setText("ADD");
        remove.setText("REMOVE");

        // setting rules
        final LayoutParams add_param = new LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        add_param.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_LEFT, aController
                .get_UI_lastItem().getId());
        add_param.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, aController.get_UI_lastItem()
                .getId());

        final LayoutParams remove_param = new LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        remove_param.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_RIGHT, aController
                .get_UI_lastItem().getId());
        remove_param.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, aController
                .get_UI_lastItem().getId());
        layout_root.addView(add, add_param);
        layout_root.addView(remove, remove_param);

        add.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // add UI
                add_UI();
                // set button at last
                add_param.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_LEFT, aController
                        .get_UI_lastItem().getId());
                add_param.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, aController
                        .get_UI_lastItem().getId());
                remove_param.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_RIGHT, aController
                        .get_UI_lastItem().getId());
                remove_param.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, aController
                        .get_UI_lastItem().getId());

            }
        });
        remove.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // remove UI
                remove_UI();
                // set button at last
                add_param.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_LEFT, aController
                        .get_UI_lastItem().getId());
                add_param.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, aController
                        .get_UI_lastItem().getId());
                remove_param.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_RIGHT, aController
                        .get_UI_lastItem().getId());
                remove_param.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, aController
                        .get_UI_lastItem().getId());
            }
        });

        // Text watcher
        TextWatcher general_text_watcher = new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                    int count) {
                // default UI
                if (editText_A.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0) {
                    editText_A.setText("0");
                }
                // dynamic UI
                if (counter > 1) {
                    for (int i = 1; i < counter; i++) {

                        if (aController.get_ui_list().get(i).getEd1().getText()
                                .toString().trim().length() == 0) {
                            aController.get_ui_list().get(i).getEd1()
                                    .setText("0");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            }
        };
        // add watcher
        editText_A.addTextChangedListener(general_text_watcher);
        // dynamic UI
        if (counter > 1) {
            for (int i = 1; i < counter; i++) {
                aController.get_ui_list().get(i).getEd1()
                        .addTextChangedListener(general_text_watcher);
            }
        }
    }

    // add UI elements
    public void add_UI() {

        EditText ed_temp = new EditText(this);
        // set id/Text
        ed_temp.setId(++id);
        ed_temp.setEms(10);

        // set rule
        LayoutParams ed_temp_param = new LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        ed_temp_param.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_LEFT, aController
                .get_UI_lastItem().getId());
        ed_temp_param.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, aController
                .get_UI_lastItem().getId());
        // add view
        layout_root.addView(ed_temp, ed_temp_param);
        // add model object
        UI_Model obj = new UI_Model(ed_temp, ed_temp.getId());
        aController.set_ui_listItem(obj);

        id++;
        counter++;
    }

    // remove UI elements
    public void remove_UI() {
        counter--;
        if (aController.get_ui_list().size() > 1) {
            layout_root.removeView(aController.get_UI_lastItem().getEd1());

            // update array list
            aController.get_ui_list().remove(
                    aController.get_ui_list().size() - 1);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "cannot remove", 1000)
                    .show();
        }
    }
}
```

Controller.java

```
public class Controller extends Application {

    // array list Model class
    ArrayList<UI_Model> ui_list = new ArrayList<UI_Model>();

    //ArrayList<Data_Model> data_list = new ArrayList<Data_Model>();

    public ArrayList<UI_Model> get_ui_list() {
        return ui_list;
    }

    public void set_ui_list(ArrayList<UI_Model> ui_list) {
        this.ui_list = ui_list;
    }

    public UI_Model get_UI_lastItem() {
        return ui_list.get(ui_list.size() - 1);
    }

    public void set_ui_listItem(UI_Model item){
        ui_list.add(item);
    }
}
```

UI_Model.java

```
public class UI_Model {

    EditText ed1;
    int id;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public UI_Model(EditText ed1, int id) {
        super();
        this.ed1 = ed1;
        this.id = id;
    }

    public UI_Model(int id) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
    }

    public EditText getEd1() {
        return ed1;
    }

    public void setEd1(EditText ed1) {
        this.ed1 = ed1;
    }
}
```

Above is my full code, my question is,

Why TextWatcher is not working on dynamic UI created at Runtime, while working on static layout UI?

Comment: then what issue you are getting using current code?

Comment: textwatcher is not getting invoked .(not working) , As default, i have used one EditText as in Layout file, and Textwatcher is working for that. Why it is not working for dynamic EditText.

Comment: ok add more code to understand issue

Comment: is it enough to getting the issue ?

Comment: post full code of class in which using `general_text_watcher`

Comment: ρяσѕρєя K@ now i have posted full code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably need to set `addTextChangedListener` listener for `EditText's` in `add_UI()` method  like:

```
ed_temp.addTextChangedListener(general_text_watcher); // set here
layout_root.addView(ed_tem‌​p, ed_temp_param);
```